# GC Function Pricing by CPU Time or Execution Time?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

Are Google Cloud Functions charged based on CPU time or execution time? The [pricing doc](https://cloud.google.com/functions/pricing#compute_time) is a little confusing on that matter.

I want to use a cloud function as a proxy that calls another endpoint. When the function needs 100ms to run (use CPU) plus 10 seconds to wait for a HTTP response (waiting for IO) do I get billed for 100ms or 10.1 seconds?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the documentation, you get billed for "wallclock" time.  This means the actual period of time (as measured by a "wall clock"), not just the time was spent executing code.  So, if your code is waiting for something, it's also spending money for that.