# Reduce Google Cloud Function CPU Second Spending

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I have a Cloud Function that sends messages via a webhook to another application. Depending on the circumstances my function is sometimes sleeping for up to 20 seconds between sending these messages. I believe this is contributing to a significant portion of the Google Cloud bill. Is there a way to wait for this period without being charged for CPU seconds, as there is actually no computation going on in these windows?

Comment: Your belief seems correct - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53117280/gc-function-pricing-by-cpu-time-or-execution-time

Comment: I see, do you know of any way I can mitigate it?

Comment: Take a look at https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/bestpractices/networking

Comment: I'll have a read, thanks

Comment: Rewrite your application so that sleeping is not required. In most cases, a function should be called and then perform a task and return. Do not wait for the steps to complete. If your design requires waiting, then add a service like Cloud Tasks.

Comment: Agree with John, you can use Cloud Task (if your process in asynchronous) with a delay timestamp to trigger the HTTP URL in the future